# Achart 1.0.0 example android API 15

Tags: android, dalvik, achartengine

Alright, I have been messing with this for a few hours now, and I can't figure out why I'm having issues.

I have been following the example from 
http://xebee.xebia.in/2010/08/31/exploring-android-charting-and-graphs-solutions/

AND 
I have already tried to create a fix using this link:
[Android achartengine simple pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591154/android-achartengine-simple-pie-chart)

AND
I have tried using the demo that achartengine provides [Here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/detail?name=achartengine-1.0.0-demo-source.zip&can=2&q=).

But that project crashed immediately after selecting a chart type on my android device.

I am new to android, and have followed those two resources almost exactly, and I'm getting this:

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

None of my src files are showing up with errors, and I have added the new activity in AndroidManifest.xml and achartengine-1.0.0.jar into my libs folder

I am using Android 4.0.3 API Level 15

I can't believe I am having this much trouble with such a seemingly simple task, but I appreciate your help.

EDIT:

this is a snippit from my log:

```
07-04 17:03:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(21611): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 17:03:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(21611): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{axiodesigns.com.caffeinezone2/axiodesigns.com.caffeinezone2.CzMain}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {axiodesigns.com.caffeinezone2/org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I have no activity called GraphicalActivity, and even after i added:

```
<activity android:name="GraphicalActivity"></activity>
```

I received the exact same error

quite a headscratcher

Comment: Have you tried to create a library project from the google's code site and rebuild it targetting API level 15 and re-add it into your project again and recompile?

Comment: yep, that was one of the first things I tried using their example script. I had to change the compiler compatibility as well.

Comment: verify that some jar isn't included twice in your project.

Comment: @tomm13b, thats where I was having the error where everything would compile, but when I would actually pick one of the chart types to view, the main would throw a fatal exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix, my build path was not recognizing that I had the .jar in my libs folder.

This fixed it:

[The application AChartengine has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160778/the-application-achartengine-has-stopped-unexpectedly-please-try-again)

Thanks for the help all