# Displaying the %ofDistribution in PieChart using aChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I am trying to create a Piechart in my android app. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591154/android-achartengine-simple-pie-chart) using achartengine helped. But I still have a problem. I want to display the % of distribution in the pie chart itself

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also looking for the same. But see the answer given by Dan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657432/how-to-set-different-values-for-legend-and-labels-in-piechart-while-i-am-using-c). I suppose he is the guy behind AChartEngine and he says that the names of legends and Labels cannot be different.

**Update:**

Although what I did to over come this was, that I made the legend size as 0. Then in the label I set the label and the computed percentage together. So, in your case, the labels would turn out to be:

Mg+ : 23%

Na+ : 45% ...so on.

**Update:2**

This issue for present in version 1.0.0 and has been solved in the latest version 1.1.0-rc2 version. You can download it from [here](http://www.achartengine.org/download/). Now as @Dan says it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657432/how-to-set-different-values-for-legend-and-labels-in-piechart-while-i-am-using-c/15471237#15471237), we can have different Legend and Label values. We can also use:

```
renderer.setDisplayValues(true);
```

to displays the percentage distribution in the pie chart itself.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks... That would help to customize the legend but I want to display the '%' near or over the pie chart. Could you pls suggest something for this too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657432/how-to-set-different-values-for-legend-and-labels-in-piechart-while-i-am-using-c/15471237#15471237 

See this link. It could be done!!

Comment: Yes. Thanks for pointing that out :) The facility became available in the latest version now. I've updates the answer as well.

Answer (score -1):

In order to get the details in % form, you can use the following :

```
renderer.setChartValuesFormat(NumberFormat.getPercentInstance());
```